# Call WebApi from Angularjs $resource passing object

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call a WebApi method from an angularjs $http function. I've tried using a standard get, query and an action name but I was corrected realizing that you can't pass an object with Get. So I'm using Post. The Web Api is being called and is returning the value I expect. However, the angularjs side is not getting the value. Here is the latest, that isn't working:

WebApi

```
[RoutePrefix("api/frequentpawner")]
    public class FrequentPawnerController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] FrequentPawnerReportCriteria criteria)
        {
            var repo = new FrequentPawnerReport();
            var result = repo.GetReport(criteria);
            var httpResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var jsonMediaTypeFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                SerializerSettings =
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                    }
            };
            httpResult.Content = new ObjectContent<List<FrequentPawnerReport>>(result, jsonMediaTypeFormatter);
            return httpResult;
        }

 function getFrequentPawner(criteria) {
            return $http.post("/api/FrequentPawner/Post", criteria)
                .then (getFrequentPawnerComplete)
                .catch(getFrequentPawnerFailed);
            function getFrequentPawnerComplete(response) {
                var x = response.data;
                return response.data.results;
            }
            function getFrequentPawnerFailed(error) {
                alert("XHR failed for frequent pawner report: " + error.responseText);
            }
        }
```

criteria object:

vm.criteria = {
        maxResults: 25,
        startDate: new Date(2014, 10, 1),
        endDate: new Date(2014, 11, 1),
        isActive: true,
        transTypeId: 1,
        jurisdictions: [],
        reportType: 1,
        relationship: 1,
        make: '',
        propertyGroupId: 0,
        propertyTypeId: 0,
        jurisdictionCount: 0,
        storeCount: 0,
        useTypePawn: false,
        useTypeScrap: false
    }

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: how it _not working_? errors in browser console? errors on server? do nothing?

Comment: first: `IEnumerable<FrequentPawnerReport> Get` if you return collection - why here `'get' : {method: 'GET', isArray: false },` you set flag _isArray_ to _false_?

Comment: Its not calling the WebApi routine at all. My understanding is that if you set isArray to false, it can return an object.

Comment: Can you provide how you setup routing?

Comment: This is the Web Api webapiconfig.cs Register method:

Comment: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
           config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
             new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
               config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "ActionApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: and also, webapi controller class

Comment: Edited to include full webapi controller class

Comment: so, i see errors in your controller, if i not mistaken: get request have no body, also your `Get` action without params

Comment: also what you pass as `criteria` parameter?

Comment: I added criteria definition.

Comment: so, methinks you a bit confused. 1) you can't pass _object_ as get url parameter, i think you can see that request was on url like this `/api/frequentPawner/[object Object]`, 2) you confuse Get method, and Post method.

Answer (score 0):

i see a few errors in your code.

1. your get method return collection, so here `'get' : {method: 'GET', isArray: false },` *isArray* flag should be *true*, otherwise you get error from angular, when get response.
2. your Get method without parameters, so possibly you need something like

   ```
   public IEnumerable<string> Get(FrequentPawnerReportCriteria criteria)
   ```
3. you confuse Get and Post methods. So, possibly, this action `FrequentPawnerReport` should be a post, and return just one object.

   ```
   public FrequentPawnerReport Post([FromBody] FrequentPawnerReportCriteria criteria)
   {
       var repo = new FrequentPawnerReport();
       return repo.GetReport(criteria);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why a Post method if I am retrieving data? The criteria object I am passing is a collection of the criteria to send through the Controller to the Repository method. Also, its not hitting Web Api controller at all. I even changed the call to retrieve the parameter-less Get and it didn't call that.

Comment: @rsalit, so you use it wrong :-) you try call from js action without params, because for action with params you add another route